# Android ffmpeg release :invalid address or address of corrupt block passed to dlfree

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

guys.I'm new to Android JNI development as well as ffmpeg libs.

With some struggles, I have managed to decode the real time H264 data, but meeting error when release the ffmpeg decoder:

```
12-11 19:54:36.428  27959-27959/com.example.firmament.dji A/libc﹕ invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x6fa13868 passed to dlfree
12-11 19:54:36.430  27959-27959/com.example.firmament.dji A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 27959 (e.firmament.dji)
```

Some questions in stackoverflow mentioned that this error related to wrongly free some memory which was protected(same with Segment Fault).

I checked the C JNI code for times and could not fix the bug, here is my code(release part):

```
jint Java_com_example_firmament_dji_XKZH264_release(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    if (pFrame != NULL) {
        av_free(pFrame);
        pFrame = NULL;
    }

    if (pCodecContext != NULL) {
        avcodec_close(pCodecContext);
        av_free(pCodecContext);
        pCodecContext = NULL;
    }

    if (pParserContext != NULL) {
        av_parser_close(pParserContext);
        av_free(pParserContext);
        pParserContext = NULL;
    }

    DeleteYUVTab();

    return 1;
}

void DeleteYUVTab()
{
    if (colortab != NULL) {
        av_free(colortab);
        colortab = NULL;
    }

    if (rgb_2_pix != NULL) {
        av_free(rgb_2_pix);
        colortab = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which android-ffmpeg you use?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, with some struggles finally I solved this.

```
av_parser_close(pParserContext);
```

This statement seems to have already free avCodecParserContext, so another av_free will results segment fault.Simply Delete it and problem solves.